# How can I draw a multiple 3d-curves picture by Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw two space curves in a same picture by Python.

So, I use two Axes3D.plot to draw the curves. But the resulting picture just shows the last one. If I use Axes3D.scatter, it can show all the points.

**Here's my codes:**

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as mt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


t=2  #t can be changed

fig = plt.figure()
ax=Axes3D(fig)

#data

def unitilize(x,y,z):
    r=mt.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)
    return x/r, y/r, z/r

def g_1(x,y,z):
    x=t*x                
    z=z/t                
    x,y,z=unitilize(x,y,z)
    return x,y,z

stepCnt=10000            ######step 
#########data#################
xs = np.empty((stepCnt + 1,))
ys = np.empty((stepCnt + 1,))
zs = np.empty((stepCnt + 1,))

#Setting initial values
def huatu(x,y,z):   

    xs[0], ys[0], zs[0] =unitilize(x,y,z)

    for i in range(stepCnt):
        xs[i+1],ys[i+1],zs[i+1]=g_1(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i])
    return xs,ys,zs


xs3,ys3,zs3=huatu(1,10,40)
ax.plot(xs3, ys3, zs3, color='b', marker='x')

xs2,ys2,zs2=huatu(1,0,40)
ax.plot(xs2, ys2, zs2, color='r', marker='o')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your image, it looks like the blue line is there, but it's hidden behind the red line (you can see blue corners sticking out of the red circles). Try changing the data in the blue line and you should be able to see it.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to make a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot!   I have found a solution. I should put 'xs = np.empty((stepCnt + 1,))'   in my function 'huatu' so that xs2 and xs3 have different datum. But I don't how this happen!

Comment: @M.JXu it looks like you're reusing `xs`, `ys`, and `zs` in the `huatu` function. After the first call to the function, it has already set these to calculated values. So the second time you call it, it's just reusing the previously calculated values. Clearing the variables with `np.empty` removes those previous values. I would suggest moving the `xs = np.empty(strpCnt + 1)` lines into your `huatu` function. There is no need for those to be outside that scope.