# Why does mutating the input to matplotlib's Axes3D.plot() and .scatter() methods behave differently?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the code posted in the question [How can I draw a multiple 3d-curves picture by Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186885/how-can-i-draw-a-multiple-3d-curves-picture-by-python), plot method is called twice and since the points to plot are not resetting, the lines are drown on top of the other. But instead of `plot()` if we try with the scatter method, we can see points plotted in different location. Why does this change in the behavior?

The code is copied below

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as mt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


t=2  #t can be changed

fig = plt.figure()
ax=Axes3D(fig)

#data

def unitilize(x,y,z):
    r=mt.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)
    return x/r, y/r, z/r

def g_1(x,y,z):
    x=t*x                
    z=z/t                
    x,y,z=unitilize(x,y,z)
    return x,y,z

stepCnt=10000            ######step 
#########data#################
xs = np.empty((stepCnt + 1,))
ys = np.empty((stepCnt + 1,))
zs = np.empty((stepCnt + 1,))

#Setting initial values
def huatu(x,y,z):   

    xs[0], ys[0], zs[0] =unitilize(x,y,z)

    for i in range(stepCnt):
        xs[i+1],ys[i+1],zs[i+1]=g_1(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i])
    return xs,ys,zs


xs3,ys3,zs3=huatu(1,10,40)
ax.plot(xs3, ys3, zs3, color='b', marker='x')

xs2,ys2,zs2=huatu(1,0,40)
ax.plot(xs2, ys2, zs2, color='r', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Plot output: 
[image]

Scatter output:
[image]

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question

Comment: The values are getting changed after calling the first plot() method.
xs3,ys3,zs3=huatu(1,10,40)
ax.plot(xs3, ys3, zs3, color='b', marker='x')

xs2,ys2,zs2=huatu(1,0,40) // here
But the changed value is being used by first plot method too. In case of scatter() those changed values are not being used. So I meant that scatter() is happening immediately. But when we call plot() it not happening immediately

Comment: @SabeerEbrahim you should edit that comment into your question (after the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you found something really weird, the *precise* source of which I haven't been able to track down. The bottom line is that lines drawn by `Axes3D.plot` (and `Axes.plot` which is how these are actually created) don't copy their input data but rather work with a view. This implies that the plot can change when the data is subsequently mutated. For some reason `Axes.plot`, which also uses views, doesn't reproduce this mutability. This might have something to do with how `Axes3D` objects are updated, I don't really know.

Anyway, `Axes3D.scatter` on the other hand creates `PathCollection` objects (cast to `PathCollection3D`), which have much more complicated internal workings. As far as I can tell, these objects (already in 2d) work with an `._offsets` property, which is an `ndarray` built from input coordinates. By construction these arrays are independent from the input data.

Let's compare the cases for `plot` to see what I mean. For a usual two-dimensional plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

# first set data to zero
# we'll use an ndarray as input, otherwise there's no chance to get a view
x = np.arange(3)
y = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])

# plot the flat line
pl, = ax.plot(x,y,'o-')

# change the axes for better comparison later; not actually relevant
ax.set_ylim([0,4])

# see that the input data are kept as views
print(pl.get_xdata().base is x)  # True
print(pl.get_ydata().base is y)  # True

# mutating x would actually change pl.get_xdata() and vice versa

# mutate y to get a nontrivial line
y[:] = [1,2,3]

# update the canvas in an interactive plot
# plt.show() probably suffices non-interactively
fig.canvas.draw()

plt.show()
```

The result contains the original flat zero line:

[image: 2d plot case]

Note that the few `print` calls in the middle verify that the data attached to the line objects created by `plot` are indeed views (rather than copies) of the input data, so the lack of effect here is due to how modifying the data is being reflected on the plots.

Compare the 3d case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

# first set data to zero
# we'll use an ndarray as input, otherwise there's no chance to get a view
x = np.arange(3)
y = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
z = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])

# plot the flat line
pl, = ax.plot(x,y,z,'o-')

# change the axes to see the result; not actually relevant
ax.set_ylim([0,4])
ax.set_zlim([0,4])

# mutate y,z to get a nontrivial line
y[:] = [1,2,3]
z[:] = [1,2,3]


# update the canvas in an interactive plot
# plt.show() probably suffices non-interactively
fig.canvas.draw()

plt.show()
```

We're doing the exact same thing only with a 3d axes object (and one more dimension), and here's the result:

[image: 3d case]

As you can see, the plot is nicely updated by the mutation of the original source arrays, in complete contrast with the 2d case.

I'm not really sure how this happens; [`Axes3D.plot`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L1506) outsources [most of the problem to `Axes.plot`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L1542) (well, the 2d part), and then [pulls out all the data along the third dimension](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L1544). Since the lines are created by `Axes.plot` in both cases, it's not surprising that neither copy their input data.

[`Axes3D.scatter`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L2294) quite similarly lets [`Axes.scatter`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L2351) do the 2d job. While I don't understand how the `plot` case differs between 2d and 3d, I find this part easier to understand: `PathCollection(3D)` objects are much more complicated and can't be assembled without decoupling yourself from the original data arrays.

So in the code in your question, the function that generates the data to plot actually mutates (and returns) the same arrays `xs,ys,zs`. Since essentially the same array is used for every plot, the result you see depends on whether the plotting call is sensitive to mutation of its data source. For `Axes3D.plot` this is the case, and thus the second call to the data generating function modifies the first plot; while for `Axes3D.scatter` mutation of the data source doesn't affect the plot, thus both plots are visible as expected.

---

If you want to see *really* weird, try my 3d example using list input instead of ndarray:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

# first set data to zero, but lists this time
x = np.arange(3)
y = [0.0,0.0,0.0]
z = [0.0,0.0,0.0]

# plot the flat line
pl, = ax.plot(x,y,z,'o-')

# change the axes to see the result; not actually relevant
ax.set_ylim([0,4])
ax.set_zlim([0,4])

# mutate y,z to get a nontrivial line
y[:] = [1,2,3]
z[:] = [1,2,3]


# update the canvas in an interactive plot
# plt.show() probably suffices non-interactively
fig.canvas.draw()

plt.show()
```

I'd expect in this case that the input lists are converted to ndarrays, and thus mutation doesn't do anything and we get a flat zero line. This is not the case:

[image: 3d case using list input]

Apparently the y coordinates doesn't change, but the z coordinates get mutated. Now this is weird! The key is the underlying data array of the plot:

```
print(pl._verts3d)
# (array([0, 1, 2]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), [1, 2, 3])
print(pl._verts3d[2] is z)
# True
```

When [`Axes3D.plot` hacks the z coordinates](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L1544) into the plot by calling [`mplot3d.art3d.line_2d_to_3d`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py#L141), the function [grabs the existing x and y arrays from the 2d plot and just slaps the z coordinates next to them](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py#L119-L131).

In other words, `Axes.plot` converts the input list `y` to an array, and at this step mutation of `y` doesn't affect the plot. The `z` input, on the other hand, is treated separately and it emerges unharmed after everything is done. This is how mutating both `y` and `z` ended up only changing `z`.

---

As a concluding remark, I looked around the matplotlib issue page, and found [this relevant discussion](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/736) for the 2d case. The resolution seems to be that it's by design that 2d plots don't copy their data, since this more often than not would add unnecessary overhead. I can also see how the 3d case is handled differently, and this leads to surprising behaviour down the line.

Anyway, I don't think it's reasonable to mutate the data passed to plotting methods. If you're doing this on purpose, use dedicated methods such as `pl.set_xdata()`. Then again this is not possible for the 3d plots (where x/ydata properties are reinterpreted to refer to different kinds of coordinates). So my suggestion is to not mutate the source arrays, or to manually pass a copy in case you want to mutate these later. Mutation can't be prohibited, but I can also see why the matplotlib developers don't want to copy every single input in every case. So the most probable solution i that the user shouldn't mutate their raw data. Something tells me that the person who wrote the code in the question didn't realize that they were mutating their inputs to begin with, which means that we're still to see a valid use case where input arrays are being mutated on purpose.

Comment: I opened [an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8990) with matplotlib, we'll see whether this is just a weird use case or there's something they can/intend to do about this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Andras Deak. Let hope for the fix from matplotlib.